# Workflow does not start automatically, when an item is modified

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a problem with my workflow on SharePoint2013.

The purpose of this workflow is to send an email (with collect data from user) where an item is modified.

- I've created a workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010 but it doesn't start automatically when an item is modified.
- In parameter, I've ticked 'start automatically when an item is modified'.
- The workflow start when i run manually.

Someone can help me?

Thank you !

Comment: can you delete/recreate the workflow?

Comment: Have you verified that the Workflow service is actively running, on the server(s)?  Sometimes the workflows take time to get in the schedule cycle.  If this is in a Farm/Garden, you need to verify that the workflow is present on each of the servers.

Comment: Ctznkane525  : yes , i have already recreate the workflow but the issue is the same.

GoldBishop: i will verify this !

Comment: @mustacruz also, what architecture is deployed?  A lot of problems I experienced with processes were due to the architecture of the SharePoint implementation.  The last one was a (2) Web -> (2) App -> (1) Database Farm Load Balancing approach; which certain processes had to be just on the Web servers, others on Web & App, a few on just App...so verify the requirement of the location for you Workflow.